# C++ too many initializer values on GENERIC_READ when creating a file mapping object

Tags: c++, file-mapping

I'm trying to create a file mapping object but I'm experiencing a few compiler errors. (I'm using MinGW GCC-8.2.0-3)

I'm getting the following error from VS-code: `too many initializer values` on the `GENERIC_READ` line.

```
HANDLE CreateFile(
    L"filename.txt",
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
```

When compiling the project I'm getting the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:5: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     );
     ^
main.cpp:18:5: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' {aka 'void*'} [-fpermissive]
```

I've tried replacing `GENERIC_READ` with `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` but the error with `too many initializer value` persists but only under the `GENERIC_READ`. Another thing I've tried with no avail was replacing `CreateFile` with `CreateFileA`. I'm including `Windows.h`.

I'm really confused on why this is happening, because under the [WIN32 API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) it states that for the `dwDesiredAccess` it is commonly used as `GENERIC_READ` or `GENERIC_WRITE` or `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `HANDLE h = CreateFile(...)`?

Comment: That solved the issue thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code, so we try to reproduce? Or, what happen if you follow [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/appending-one-file-to-another-file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jarod42 for the answer.

I had to assign the file handle to a variable:

```
HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
    _T("combatlog.txt"),
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
```